# Deploying/Hosting .Net Web Service on SSRS

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api-routing, ssrs-2012

I was wondering if anyone knew if it was technically possible to deploy an asp.net web service to an SSRS 2012 Report Server, which could host the service with functionality similar to that of an actual web server. The report server is seldom used and I would like to utilize it as a web server, if Visual Studio and the other parts involved would allow for such. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: A server is a server. As long as it has IIS, it can be a web server. Just because it is currently being used for SSRS doesn't mean that it's just a "report server" - you can put websites, SQL Server instances, FTP sites, whatever you want on it. Also, Visual Studio doesn't have anything to do with it - your published web application is totally separate from the IDE - its requirements would just be IIS, the appropriate .NET Framework version, and ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks Joe. It seems that newer versions of SSRS no longer use IIS. It's a virtual directory that's using its own http.sys and complex architecture, which makes me guess the chances for incompatibility are high